# Python conditional removal of element

Tags: python, celementtree

I am parsing a large XML file using Python and stuck on a condition removal of an element. I have checked the logic as has another person, however for whatever reason it still doesn't work. Essentially I am trying to remove Non-Preffered Terms that are non-English as we don't require them in our system. So a term might look like the following

```
<Subject>
<Terms>
<Non-Preferred_Term>
<Term_Text>hanging buttress</Term_Text>
<Term_Language>Dutch</Term_Language>
</Non-Preferred_Term>
More terms...
</Terms>
</Subject>
```

Essentially my logic goes like this find the terms Element, find the non-preferred-term, look at the language for each and if the language doesn't match English then remove the term.

```
for terms in term.iterfind ("Terms"):
    for term in terms.iterfind ("Non-Preferred_Term"):
        for language in term.iterfind ("Term_Language"):
            if language.text != ("English"):
                print (language.text)
                term.remove (term)
                print ("term deleted")
```

When I run the script on my test file it seems to work in that I get a print out of each language text that isn't English as it runs followed by term deleted. However when I look at the ouput file the none english terms are still in the file. When I try it on my 700mb file it seems to generally work but crashes out sometimes with x is not in list.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This `term.remove(term)` looks suspect. You can't remove an object from itself... can you?

Comment: @Sam Why not? `x=[]; x.append(x); x.remove(x)` works just fine :P Edit: Not saying it's the correct thing to do here though.

Comment: that my error it should indeed be terms.remove(term). I am removing the child term from the terms list.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a reference issue. You have:

```
for terms in term.iterfind('Term'):
    for term in terms:
```

So `term` is a variable before any of the loops, but then you re-use that name in the inner for loop.